# How to loop user input in Python Selenium if the input is invalid and doesn't trigger the if in while loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting a NoSuchWindowException if I close the window manually but if I leave it the program gets stuck after I enter the tenant name. It doesn't give me the "Sorry, I didn't understand that." print.

I'm trying to execute this code if the user enters the correct input it triggers the if in the dropdown while loop but if they don't enter the correct input I want the user to be asked to enter the tenant name again.

[Current Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSHa0.png)

Comment: Please never post code as images, simply copy/paste your code into the question and format it as code.